# How to get test coin for Rinkeby Metamask

Tags: metamask, rinkeby

I create a wallet on metamask and i would like to play with rinkeby test net. I can't get the coins through the twitter procedure. I attach already that I come out, can someone help me? thanks

Comment: use ropsten or any other test network, it is easiert to get coins there

Comment: Thank you. I try to use it and it seems should be done but I can't see any coins into my wallet. how is possible? Isn't immediate?

Comment: Which webpage u used to get the coins?

Comment: for kovan test this https://gitter.im/kovan-testnet/faucet

Comment: i can send you a very littel amount of test ether, post your public key here

Comment: I use twitter and fb as a public pages. I I would be very grateful if you sent them to me. Do test coins have an expiration date?
This is my public key: 0x4e6bCeF79A19747ddc22597dA1BE1D21f0ffd529

Comment: Okay I will do tomorrow in about 9 hours, no they don't have

Comment: you already have 3 Ether on Rinkeby
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x4e6bcef79a19747ddc22597da1be1d21f0ffd529
you also have some on kovan.. on Ropsten i sent to you 0.3 ether

Comment: J'ai une préoccupation, je reçu des ETH sur le test net rinketby.
Après avoir eu des ETH dans rinketby, sont t'il retirable et échangeable ? Si oui comment procéder ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to request Ether in a faucet.

If you select "buy" option in Metamask extension, you will see 2 options, the one in the bottom says "Try Faucet", and it will lead you to:  https://faucet.metamask.io/

Also, you can copy your address in Metamask, and paste it here:
https://faucet.rinkeby.io/

There are more public faucets, if you need it, some times they are not available for a period of time, and there is a limit in the number of tokens you can request.

Just google: "*Rinkeby Faucet*" and you will have some useful results.

**UPDATE:**

If you switch to Ropsten, you will get test ETH very easy [in this faucet](https://faucet.ropsten.be/).

Comment: not successful yet

Comment: Are you using Rinkeby for any reason? I always prefer to use Ropsten network, is super easy to get ethers here: https://faucet.ropsten.be/

Comment: that Ropsten faucet is not working ... :/

Comment: Are you connected to Ropsten, in Metamask? It works great for me (every 24 hours).